# SpringBoot como obtener nombres de los campos de un colección MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

¿Hay alguna forma de obtener los campos de un documento en Spring boot? o no se puede.
Quiero adaptar este código de MongoDB a SpringBoot.

```
var map = function() {
    for (var key in this) { 
        emit(key, null); 
    }
}

var reduce = function(key, stuff) { 
    return null; 
}

var mr = db.documento.mapReduce(
    map,
    reduce,
    {out: "documento_keys"}
)

db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
```

Con el código de arriba nos permite mostrar los campos que maneja una colección y ahora este es mi código  en SpringBoot por el momento.

```
public void obtenerCampos(){
    String map = "function () { "+
                    "for (var key in this) {"+ 
                        "emit(key, null);"+
                    "}"+
                "}";
    String reduce = "function (key, values) { "+
                        "return null;"+
                    "}";
    MapReduceResults<Documento> result = mongoTemplate.mapReduce("documento", map, reduce, Documento.class);
    for(Documento doc: result){
        System.out.println(doc.toString());
    }

}
```

Pero no obtengo el resultado que quiero no se que código mas me falta por completar.
Necesito una mano, claro si es que es posible hacer como dice la pregunta.